# Oracle VM VirtualBox "instruction at 0x806d58e2 referenced memory at 0x00000000" error

Tags: virtualbox

When I start Oracle VM VirtualBox 4.2.18 on Windows 8.1 64bit, the below message shows. What is the meaning of this message and how to solve it?

> VBoxTestOGL.exe
>
> The instruction at 0x806d58e2 referenced memory at 0x00000000. The memory could not be read.

[image]

Comment: I had a similar issue on v6.1.8, except that the second address was not 0x0. I was able to fix it by changing the graphics controller on my VM to VMSVGA. The only downside to this is that it currently causes a warning message about window resizing to be displayed. This seems to be because only VBoxVGA and VBoxSVGA support resizing the window. VMSVGA only supports resizing using the guest system display controls.

Answer (score 9):

Try disabling 3D accelaration on the Guest. There are some reported problems with AMD graphics cards with 3D acceleration enabled.

See e.g. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12772

Comment: This fix worked for my NVidia GeForce GTX 980M.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

VirtualBox has tried to read a memory location without permissions. In the main memory there are some areas that only the kernel can read/write. This is the meaning of the message.

Could exist many reasons that triggered this error.
I suggest to install another version... maybe you can try with 32bit version.

Comment: Seems that `0x00000000` indicates that it didn't actually specify which memory it wanted to read?

Comment: yes, it could be

Answer (score 2):

In the last 1-2 years I've been continously using the newest VirtualBox on a Win7 host, starting up the same WinXP host occasionaly. (Current version is VirtualBox 4.3.20)

I'm using a dual display setup, and the occurence of the error is determined by the screen on which the VirtualBox window is started. If I use screen 1, the error never happens. If the VirtualBox window resides on screen 2 at a critical moment of the guest WinXP bootup, the error shows up. If I start the virtual machine on screen 1, let the guest WinXP boot up, then move the window to screen 2, no errors are experienced for the rest of the session. So I started to do exactly this as a workaround.

May as well work (or not) in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a mistmatch between the VirtualBox version, e.g. 6.1.36, and the VirtualBox Extension Pack, e.g. 6.1.34. After installing the matched version of the Extension Pack, everything worked well again.

This error happened to both already created VMs as well as being-created VMs.

Comment: This is the answer that solved my problem. Unfortunately I had already deleted my vm and I need to start my configuration from scratch again